# Error creating the secondary buffer DirectSound

Tags: c++, directsound

I don't know if I should reply to my previous question or I should to ask a new one

For a project for my university I have to create a client/server application where the client and the server communicate through sockets and the client streams WAV files from the server using DirectSound API

the server and the client communication through sockets its working but when I am choose which file to play I am getting this message:
[image]

```
 // Initialize DirectSound
    IDirectSound8* dsound;
    if (DirectSoundCreate8(NULL, &dsound, NULL) != DS_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error initializing DirectSound" << std::endl;
        closesocket(socket_client);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (dsound->SetCooperativeLevel(GetDesktopWindow(), DSSCL_PRIORITY) != DS_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error setting cooperative level" << std::endl;
        dsound->Release();
        closesocket(socket_client);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create primary buffer
    DSBUFFERDESC primary_buffer_desc;
    memset(&primary_buffer_desc, 0, sizeof(primary_buffer_desc));
    primary_buffer_desc.dwSize = sizeof(primary_buffer_desc);
    primary_buffer_desc.dwFlags = DSBCAPS_PRIMARYBUFFER;
    IDirectSoundBuffer* primary_buffer;
    if (dsound->CreateSoundBuffer(&primary_buffer_desc, &primary_buffer, NULL) != DS_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error creating primary buffer" << std::endl;
        dsound->Release();
        closesocket(socket_client);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Set primary buffer format
    WAVEFORMATEX primary_buffer_format;
    memset(&primary_buffer_format, 0, sizeof(primary_buffer_format));
    primary_buffer_format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    primary_buffer_format.nChannels = 2;
    primary_buffer_format.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
    primary_buffer_format.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    primary_buffer_format.nBlockAlign = primary_buffer_format.nChannels * primary_buffer_format.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    primary_buffer_format.nAvgBytesPerSec = primary_buffer_format.nSamplesPerSec * primary_buffer_format.nBlockAlign;
    if (primary_buffer->SetFormat(&primary_buffer_format) != DS_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error setting primary buffer format" << std::endl;
        primary_buffer->Release();
        dsound->Release();
        closesocket(socket_client);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create secondary buffer
    DSBUFFERDESC secondary_buffer_desc;
    memset(&secondary_buffer_desc, 0, sizeof(secondary_buffer_desc));
    secondary_buffer_desc.dwSize = sizeof(secondary_buffer_desc);
    secondary_buffer_desc.dwFlags = 0;
    secondary_buffer_desc.dwBufferBytes = file_size;
    secondary_buffer_desc.lpwfxFormat = &primary_buffer_format;

    IDirectSoundBuffer* secondary_buffer;
    if (dsound->CreateSoundBuffer(&secondary_buffer_desc, &secondary_buffer, NULL) != DS_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error creating secondary buffer" << std::endl;
        primary_buffer->Release();
        dsound->Release();
        closesocket(socket_client);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
```

DirectSound documentation is confusing me and I can't find why is not working properly

Comment: Recommendation: display text as text. If you can copy-n-paste the error message as text into the question, do it. [It makes life easier for those who follow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301), and if life is easier, that generally shows up in the reputation of the question over time.

Comment: Print out (or check in the debugger) the error code returned by `CreateSoundBuffer`.  Don't leave yourself (and us) guessing.

Comment: Note that DirectSound is very much legacy at this point. You may want to take a look at XAudio2 or Windows Core Sound API (WASAPI). If you need to stick with legacy DirectSound, take a look at the [old samples](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-legacy-samples/tree/main/DirectSound).